# Multiple threads modifying a collection in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

The project I am working on requires a whole bunch of queries towards a database. In principle there are two types of queries I am using:

1. read from excel file, check for a couple of parameters and do a query for hits in the database. These hits are then registered as a series of custom classes. Any hit may (and most likely will) occur more than once so this part of the code checks and updates the occurrence in a custom list implementation that extends ArrayList.
2. for each hit found, do a detail query and parse the output, so that the classes created in (I) get detailed info.

I figured I would use multiple threads to optimize time-wise. However I can't really come up with a good way to solve the problem that occurs with the collection these items are stored in. To elaborate a little bit; throughout the execution objects are supposed to be modified by both (I) and (II).

I deliberately didn't c/p any code, as it would be big chunks of code to make any sense.. I hope it make some sense with the description above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 5 and above, you may either use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or a [synchronized wrapper around your list](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29). In earlier Java versions, only the latter choice is available. The same is true if you absolutely want to stick to the custom `ArrayList` implementation you mention.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` is feasible if the container is read much more often than written (changed), which seems to be true based on your explanation. Its atomic `addIfAbsent()` method may even help simplify your code.

**[Update]** On second thought, a map sounds more fitting to the use case you describe. So if changing from a list to e.g. a map is an option, you should consider [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). **[/Update]**

Changing the objects within the container does not affect the container itself, however you need to ensure that the objects themselves are thread-safe.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList is a very slow (and memory hungry) data structure - it also doesn't extend ArrayList so he can use a more effecient class like ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Comment: Also, as long as you stick to a producer/consumer model (i.e. a thread removes an object from the queue, edits it, then puts it back (or to a different queue)) then the objects themselves have no need to be thread-safe.

Comment: @Gandalf, CopyOnWriteArrayList is slow only on writes. What is described in the post above, to me, is very different from a producer-consumer model, so queues are not an option.

Comment: Thanks to both Peter and Gandalf, and sorry for the late reply. I have been working on a number of other functions for the project. 

I havent had the chance to try these on as the multithreading was deprioritised in favor of implementation of some other functions. Will get back when/if I get the chance to try these out.

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Just use the new `java.util.concurrent` packages.

Classes like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and `ConcurrentHashMap` are already there for you to use and are all thread-safe.